# how to call aspx variable in .js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a requirement of adding server side variables in client side and other way round. Because I need to set a value from client side using javascript and access the same in code behind page.

I have to use C#.Net and javascript.

Any directions please

Comment: i need to call my c# variable to .java script  file .

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can use `hidden filed` or `cookie` etc variable to set values from javascript or server side and get the values on both side.

Comment: if i have a separate js file , how it possible   i need to access string firstname="something" ; i need to use this in myscript.js